# Unix-Sorting the data in different positions of a file

Tags: sorting, unix

I want to sort the data in a file from different positions like 2-5, 7-9, 15-18, 30-33 and so on..i have tried using -k option but its not working..can some body please help me in this?

Comment: Post your attempt. And a peek at a line or two of the data would be useful, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sorting numeric data then you have 2 options. You can call sort -n to sort the numeric values or you need to make sure that each value has the same number of characters.  For example, if you have the values 1, 2, 3, and 11 the sort command will return 1, 11, 2, 3.  That's because it's treating the values as text, not as numeric values.  You can solve this by storing the numbers in the form 01, 02, 03, and 11 which will cause the sort command to return 01, 02, 03, and 11.

Comment: Or use the `-n` (numeric sort) option. http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html

Comment: Actually i have to migrate the functionality of Sort in Maniframe to Unix platform. In mainframe they are using sort functionality to sort the data, the same functionality has to be achieved in Unix environent, but i have tried using the sort command but its not working. (Ex:045000022014-04-2300131200000007 05 1234947738, sort from 3-6, 9-11,15-18, etc) but its not working with -k option. Please help me in this. Its has to be fixed ASAP.